# Eclipse Juno with PyDev deletes my django files

Tags: django, eclipse, pydev

I was trying to set up the Eclipse on a new computer, and thought I might as well try Juno instead of Indigo as I was using before.

However, attempting to import my PyDev/Django files was troublesome, and I ended up creating a new Django project and copying my source files in.

However, when I hit Refresh, Eclipse deletes a bunch of files including urls.py!

I've given up for now - back to Notepad++ - but does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

I must say that'd be the first time I heard that PyDev was deleting .py files... (it does have an option to remove orphaned .pyc files which you can disable on window > preferences > pydev > builders > how to handle .pyc/$py.class deletion).

Are you sure that it's really deleting those files in the filesystem? Can you reproduce that? (if so, please provide the steps to do so, because I've tried many things here and haven't been able to duplicate that behavior). It'd be nice if you check if it really removes the files in the filesystem (i.e.: it's possible that for some reason it's only filtering those in the PyDev package explorer?)

Comment: This just happened to me also; while using eclipse and pydev in the debug view, the debug session threw an exception and quit my script. On termination, two of my open editor windows prompted me that my files were changed on disc, so I chose to refresh. The files weren't just changed, the files were deleted from disc. Happy to help you provide any steps to repro. I enjoy using pydev.

Comment: This was in a non-package class, and the files were really removed from the filesystem.

Comment: If you are able to reproduce it, please create a bug-report (see: http://pydev.org/about.html for links to report a bug).

Comment: The version of eclipse I have is not Juno, it is Version: 3.7.2
Build id: M20120208-0800. So, if this is related, it is not Juno-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I just lost 3 hours of work using pydev and eclipse, without using django. So this is not django specific.

Comment: Just to note, if you had the file open in eclipse, you can restore it from there.

Comment: I.e.: see: http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2008/1/18/How-to-recover-a-deleted-file-in-Eclipse

Comment: I wasn't thinking, and told the IDE to refresh from disc, so I threw out my work. The IDE says 'No deleted resources in local history for selected container' when I try this trick.

Comment: I've opened https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7243 even though I can't reproduce this again.